# Themed attribute not required for Dynamic links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

When I create a blog from orchard dashboard, It asks me the url for the blog, For that link I dont want to get [themed] attribute. How can I achieve it. It is getting dynamically.

Comment: "It is getting dynamically", what do you want to achieve? Do you mean that you load it through Ajax?

Comment: For the blogs module I don't need [themed] attribute. I had removed the [themed] attribute from it's controller's it is working for the view, but when I click more comments, I'm getting all the comments in Theme. I dont want theme to entire blogs module.

Comment: It's bad practice to customize things by modifying the module's code. Why do you want it to be unthemed?

Comment: It's all organisation requirement. For now we don't want the theme to the blogs module.

Comment: We want that module without theme.

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16947974/3153169)

Comment: That link says all about creation of new module and its routing.

Comment: Yeah, you know what best practices mean? One thing in orchard is that you don't change any (core) existing modules, but instead override functionality in your own module

Comment: Yes thank you devqon. I think now I'm getting your point. How can I override that entire orchard.blog module in my module ?

Comment: How about starting with the link I just gave you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there is two ways to disable theme in orchard:
1) If you want to disable theme on any content type (like: Blog), you can attach DisableThemePart to it, and it will handle this for you.
2) If you want to disable theme on an action or route you don't have access to customise it (like orchard modules builtin controllers), you can do it by adding new filter to handle the request to this action, then use the following code:

```
public class DisableThemeFilter : FilterProvider, IActionFilter 
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == "Item" &&
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName == "Blog")
        {
            ThemeFilter.Disable(filterContext.RequestContext);
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the reply. From your first point : Where I need to attach DisableThemePart ?

Comment: You can do it either from the dashboard or migration:
1) From dashboard:Be sure that "Content Types" module is enabled, then go to "Content Definition" from admin left menu, then press Edit for "Blog" type, then press "Add Parts", from this screen select "Disable Theme" then press save.
2) From Migration: add the following code to your module migration file:
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Blog",
                cfg => cfg
                    .WithPart("DisableThemePart")
);